# Input element size attribute doesn't visually match digits on display

Tags: html, input

Say I have an input element that is four digits. I want to make sure the input element visually presents that fact without ambiguity. However I find that most browsers seem to present [size](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-size-attribute)=4 as size=6. Why? And how do I achieve what I want?

```html
<input type=text value=123456 size=4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite know why `size` attribute is so inaccurate, but if I need to have a good fit, I'll use 1ch per character and 1px of padding. ch is a unit of measurement that is about the width of a zero. It's relative to the font used so it varies but it's very accurate if used for measuring how much space characters actually use.

It just occured to me if you want the actual character spaces to be 6 or less, you'll need to use `maxlength`. So a combination of 6ch width and the `maxlength='6'` is perfect.

Just found this [article](http://html.com/attributes/input-size/) which explains why `size` is the way it is. Apparently, `size` is based on font-size,

> both the font-size property (12 pt vs. 14 pt) and the relative size of the font being used (Arial vs.Helvetica`, for example).

Read more: http://html.com/attributes/input-size/#ixzz4VyvrKPLm

**SNIPPET**

```css
input {
  width: 6ch;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='123456'>

<input type='text' maxlength='6' value='123456'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 4ch;
}
```

Comment: You should probably have 4ch in place of 6ch. Apart from that, try explaining what it does and how it answers the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxlength` attribute to set a pre-defined size to allow that many characters for an input.

If you want it to be interactive, using JS might be overkill for this, but the following adapts the input text-box size based on the input.

```html
<body onload="len()">

<input id="input" type="text" value=123456 size=4 onblur="len()">

<script>
function len() {
    var n = document.getElementById("input").value.length;
    document.getElementById("input").size = n;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try `oninput` instead of  `onblur`